# Auth-Type :- Reject in RADIUS users file matches inner tunnel request but sends Access-Accept

Tags: ldap, radius, freeradius, wpa2, eap

I have WPA2 802.11x EAP authentication setup using FreeRADIUS 2.1.8 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 talking to OpenLDAP, and can successfully authenticate using PEAP/MSCHAPv2, TTLS/MSCHAPv2 and TTLS/PAP (both via the AP and using [eapol_test](http://deployingradius.com/scripts/eapol_test/)). I am now trying to restrict access to specific SSIDs based on the LDAP groups which the user belongs to.

I have configured group membership checking in `/etc/freeradius/modules/ldap` like so:

```
groupname_attribute = cn
groupmembership_filter = "(|(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid=%{User-Name}))(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(uniquemember=%{User-Name})))"
```

and I have configured extraction of the SSID from Called-Station-Id into Called-Station-SSID based on the [Mac Auth](http://wiki.freeradius.org/Mac-Auth#Additional+modifications) wiki page. In `/etc/freeradius/eap.conf` I have enabled copying attributes from the outer tunnel into the inner tunnel, and usage of the inner tunnel response in the outer tunnel (for both PEAP and TTLS). I had the same behaviour before changing these options however.

```
copy_request_to_tunnel = yes
use_tunneled_reply = yes
```

I'm running `eapol_test` like this to test the setup:

```
eapol_test -c peap-mschapv2.conf -a 172.16.0.16 -s testing123 -N 30:s:01-23-45-67-89-01:Example-EAP
```

with the following `peap-mschapv2.conf` file:

```
network={
    ssid="Example-EAP"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=PEAP
    identity="mgorven"
    anonymous_identity="anonymous"
    password="foobar"
    phase2="autheap=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

With the following in `/etc/freeradius/users`:

```
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "employees"
```

and running `freeradius-Xx`, I can see that the LDAP group retrieval works, and that the SSID is extracted.

```
Debug:   [ldap] performing search in dc=example,dc=com, with filter (&(cn=employees)(|(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid=mgorven))(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(uniquemember=mgorven))))
Debug: rlm_ldap::ldap_groupcmp: User found in group employees
...
Info:        expand: %{7} -> Example-EAP
```

Next I try to only allow access to users in the `employees` group (regardless of SSID), so I put the following in `/etc/freeradius/users`:

```
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "employees"

DEFAULT Auth-Type := Reject
```

But this immediately rejects the Access-Request in the outer tunnel because the `anonymous` user is not in the `employees` group. So I modify it to only match inner tunnel requests like so:

```
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "employees"

DEFAULT FreeRADIUS-Proxied-To == "127.0.0.1"
        Auth-Type := Reject, Reply-Message = "User does not belong to any groups which may access this SSID."
```

Now users which are in the `employees` group are authenticated, but so are users which are not in the `employees` group. I see the reject entry being matched, and the Reply-Message is set, but the client receives an Access-Accept.

```
Debug: rlm_ldap::ldap_groupcmp: Group employees not found or user is not a member.
Info: [files] users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 209
Info: ++[files] returns ok
...
Auth: Login OK: [mgorven] (from client test port 0 cli 02-00-00-00-00-01 via TLS tunnel)
Info:   WARNING: Empty section.  Using default return values.
...
Info: [peap] Got tunneled reply code 2
        Auth-Type := Reject
        Reply-Message = "User does not belong to any groups which may access this SSID."
...
Info: [peap] Got tunneled reply RADIUS code 2
        Auth-Type := Reject
        Reply-Message = "User does not belong to any groups which may access this SSID."
...
Info: [peap] Tunneled authentication was successful.
Info: [peap] SUCCESS
Info: [peap] Saving tunneled attributes for later
...
Sending Access-Accept of id 11 to 172.16.2.44 port 60746
        Reply-Message = "User does not belong to any groups which may access this SSID."
        User-Name = "mgorven"
```

and `eapol_test` reports:

```
RADIUS message: code=2 (Access-Accept) identifier=11 length=233
   Attribute 18 (Reply-Message) length=64
      Value: 'User does not belong to any groups which may access this SSID.'
   Attribute 1 (User-Name) length=9
      Value: 'mgorven'
...
SUCCESS
```

Why isn't the request being rejected, and is this the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some strange reason, setting `Auth-Type` is a **check** item, not a **reply** item, and therefore this must be done on the first line of the rule. The following works correctly:

```
DEFAULT FreeRADIUS-Proxied-To == "127.0.0.1", Auth-Type := Reject
    Reply-Message = "User does not belong to any groups which may access this SSID."
```